# How to solve using groupby in python?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-science

We have the following table:

- Visitor_id
- Event_name
- Story
- Chapter

Story consists of chapters. A user reads a chapter and then hits the paywall to continue to the next chapter where she can either do a purchase or wait for the next day to read the next chapter.

Event names can have following values: “read”, “purchase”

```
      visitor_id event_name story  chapter
0           1       read    s1        1
1           1       read    s1        2
2           1   purchase    s1        2
3           1       read    s1        3
4           1       read    s1        4
5           1       read    s2        1
6           2       read    s3        1
7           2   purchase    s3        1
8           2       read    s3        2
9           3       read    s3        1
```

Calculate average purchases per reader per story

Comment: I assume you can only purchase a story once.

Comment: @Tarik It sounds like you can purchase it n-1 where n is the number of chapters

Comment: If this is `sql` related please tag it as such.

Comment: @Tarik How would you solve it using python ?

Comment: @Chris How to solve via python groupby operator ?

Comment: What's your attempt at solving it? Kindly share what have you tried so that we can help.

Comment: @MohitMunjal I have posted the Answer to hat I have solved please let me know if it is done rightly.

Comment: I tried to edit the code from your answer into the question, since it belongs in the question. I also tried to fix your question so that it is an actual question. However, you are still missing information. For example, you should show what the result should be for this input, and explain how that is different from the result that you got. You  should also explain what you think is the difficulty in getting the right answer, or what seems to have gone wrong in your approach.

Comment: Also, to be clear: the chapter information does not matter to the problem, right? You should try to explain the logical steps to solving the problem. For example, what should the rows be that go into a given group, and what will you do with each group in order to get the answer?

Comment: @karlKnechtel Wohat do you thibk is wrong in my approach and what do you think according to you is the right asnwer ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the follwing code to solve the problem:

- Firstly I set Read = 1 and then Purchase = 0.

The applied code used was as follows :

```
df.groupby(['story']).mean().groupby('story')['event_name'].mean().reset_index(name='avg purchases per reader')
```

The output which I got was as follows :

```
    story avg purchases per reader
0   s1       0.80
1   s2       1.00
2   s3       0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want purchase to be 1, and read to be zero, so that the average actually represents the number of purchases.  You can use map to do this, then groupby/mean.

Since you said you want the average purchases per user, per story, you need both of those in your groupby.

```
df['event_name'] = df['event_name'].map({'read':0, 'purchase':1})
df = df.groupby(['visitor_id','story'])['event_name'].mean().reset_index(name='average_purchases')
```

Output

```
   visitor_id story  average_purchases
0           1    s1           0.200000
1           1    s2           0.000000
2           2    s3           0.333333
3           3    s3           0.000000
```